# react and redux props differences

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have app.js and component.js
component.js is in app.js
in my redux,
there is number and
"number+1" function and
"number-1 "function.

when i use redux props,

```
export default function Sample2({ props }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.num}</h2>
      <button onClick={props.onClickIncrease}>+</button>
      <button onClick={props.onClickDecrease}>-</button>
    </div>

  );
}
```

this works

and

```
export default function Sample2( props ) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.num}</h2>
      <button onClick={props.onClickIncrease}>+</button>
      <button onClick={props.onClickDecrease}>-</button>
    </div>

   
  );
}
```

doesn't work

my app.js is

```
<Sample
          num={props.num}
          onClickIncrease={props.onClickIncrease}
          onClickDecrease={props.onClickDecrease}
        />
```

i made component like this.

is there difference using {} on props?

Comment: How does your `redux` code look like? Can you share all your code so we may be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course there is a difference here is a small example perhaps it will explain the situation

```js
const sameFunction1 = ({props}) => {
  console.log(props.num)
}

const sameFunction2 = (props) => {
  console.log(props.num)
}

sameFunction1({
  props: {
      num: 1  // <-------
  },
  num:2 
})

sameFunction2({
  props: {
      num: 1 
  },
  num:2 // <-------
})
```

To tell the truth, the question does not concern `react` and `redux`, the question concerns `destructurization`.

In the first case we do it, in the second we don't, in the first case we extract props from the object in the second we work with the whole object

In other words:

```
const sameFunction1 = ({props}) => {
  console.log(props.num)
}
```

it equal below code:

```
const sameFunction1 = (data) => {
  const props = data.props // const {props} = data.props
  console.log(props.num)
}
```